# when I run a bash file manually, it works, but crontab can not run it?

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, youtube, download-manager

This is my sh-file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5816543/, that I use this to download youtube files in a specific period per day. when I drag the file (y.sh) into the terminal and press return key, it starts to download. but when I use the below command in `crontab -e`, Nothing happens!

```
00 21 * * * /home/deroot/links4dl/y.sh
```

---

Torify: wrapper for torsocks or tsocks and tor -> `man torify`

youtube-dl: download videos from youtube.com or other video platforms -> `man youtube-dl`

Comment: if any of those commands post output to the screen it is NOT going to work. I would ALWAYS reroute errors and notices to `/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Also, always use the full path when using crontab. That, or make sure that the shell running the script has the same `$PATH` variable as your interactive bash session.

Comment: And if you do not use an absolute path add $PATH to your crontab ;) example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129381/crontab-path-and-user

Comment: Or, you can try redirecting the output to a file, so you can see the errors. So, you would do `00 21 * * * /home/deroot/links4dl/y.sh > /home/deroot/ScriptLog`

Comment: @Alaa `00 21 * * * /home/deroot/links4dl/y.sh > /home/deroot/ScriptLog 2>&1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Cron uses its own environment, which is different of your own environment.

If you didn't changed it, in cron environment $PATH is `/usr/bin:/bin`

You can check where your command are stored with that commands:

```
which torify 
which youtube-dl
```

if its not in `/usr/bin:/bin`
=> Add a minimal PATH environment into your script, something like:

`export PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:xxxx"`

(where xxxx is the path to your command )

Comment: note that @Rinzwind pointed that you can add the PATH to the crontab itself.